# Can't get takeUntil to cancel the request

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

After dispatching `SEARCH`, I'm trying to cancel an AJAX request but also to keep the observable listening. I'm using `takeUntil` and waiting for an action of type `CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS` to cancel the request.

Here's my epic:

```
const searchEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SEARCH).pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(({ payload }) =>
            search(query).pipe(
                map(({ response }) => SearchActions.searchSuccess(response)),  // dispatches SEARCH_SUCCESS
                takeUntil(
                    action$.ofType(CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS)
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

**Edit:** I have a Redux logger which outputs dispatched actions in the following order:

1. `SEARCH`
2. `SEARCH`
3. `SEARCH`
4. `SEARCH`
5. `CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS`
6. `SEARCH_SUCCESS`

(each `SEARCH` is a keystroke)

Comment: So where's the problem? Any errors? What you have now looks fine. How you know it's not canceled or it doesn't simply come after the request is done.

Comment: I've edited my post, please have a look

Comment: What you have look fine so the problem is probably somewhere else. Otherwise make a demo reproducing the problem.

Comment: Hey @martin, sorry for the late response. Here's a repo with a demo: https://github.com/eyal0803/job-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by moving the `takeUntil` outside of the `switchMap` and putting a `repeat()` after it, like so:

```
const searchEpic = action$ =>
    action$.ofType(SEARCH).pipe(
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(({ payload }) =>
            search(query).pipe(
                map(({ response }) => SearchActions.searchSuccess(response))
            )
        ),
        takeUntil(action$.ofType(CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS)),
        repeat()
    )
```

The problem was that the epic starts listening for `CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS` only after the 500ms of the `debounceTime`, which is not what I wanted.

All credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45514147/1652265) by [Jay Phelps](https://github.com/jayphelps) and to [Evert Bouw](https://github.com/evertbouw) for finding and pointing it out to me on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/redux-observable/redux-observable?at=5bd06202ae7be94016aa99f6).